# .ix alternative in the code

Tags: python, pandas

I want to run a code to check what is happening inside this but I am not able to execute this, there is a message saying .ix is deprecated.

outlier = 4 #outlier

```
for k in np.arange(0,3,1):

    wAvg = sum(df.ix[:,1] * df.ix[:,2]) #Weight Average
    Std = df.ix[:,2].std()
    df.ix[:,2] = (df.ix[:,2]-wAvg)/Std

    df.ix[df.ix[:,2] > outlier,  2] =  outlier
    df.ix[df.ix[:,2] < -outlier, 2] = -outlier
```

I am new to python and I just want to understand the logic so that I can create one document for this. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like need indexing by positions, so change `ix` to `iloc`.

So for first row need change:

```
wAvg = sum(df.ix[:,1] * df.ix[:,2])
```

to:

```
wAvg = sum(df.iloc[:,1] * df.iloc[:,2])
```

And for filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) need `loc` and select columns names by indexing by `df.columns[2]`:

```
df.ix[df.ix[:,2] > outlier,  2] =  outlier
df.ix[df.ix[:,2] < -outlier, 2] = -outlier
```

to:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,2] > outlier,  df.columns[2]] =  outlier
df.loc[df.iloc[:,2] < -outlier, df.columns[2]] = -outlier
```

For more information check [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated).

EDIT:

```
for k in np.arange(0,3,1):

    wAvg = sum(df.iloc[:,1] * df.iloc[:,2]) #Weight Average
    Std = df.iloc[:,2].std()
    df.iloc[:,2] = (df.iloc[:,2]-wAvg)/Std

    df.loc[df.iloc[:,2] > outlier,  df.columns[2]] =  outlier
    df.loc[df.iloc[:,2] < -outlier,df.columns[2]] = -outlier
```

Comment: i am getting this error : NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available.

code :


     for k in np.arange(0,3,1):

    wAvg = sum(df.iloc[:,1] * df.iloc[:,2]) #Weight Average
    Std = df.iloc[:,2].std()
    df.iloc[:,2] = (df.iloc[:,2]-wAvg)/Std

    df.iloc[df.iloc[:,2] > outlier,  2] =  outlier
    df.iloc[df.iloc[:,2] < -outlier, 2] = -outlier

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: can you give me the whole code at once? I am getting an error.

Comment: I have no your data, so not possible check another solution - change `ix` to `loc`. But I hope EDIT answer working nice.

Comment: That is working perfectly. Thanks for your help, sir.